# Serialize an Array of Integers with a Serializable RealmObject

Tags: java, android, realm, serializable

I'm using an endpoint that is returning an array of integers indicating the allowed payment types I can use, for example:

```
[0,1,2,3]
```

However, I am not able to map it into a list. I already tried a simple Integer List.

```
@SerializedName("permitted_payment_types")
public List<Integer> paymentTypes;
```

I get the following error.

> Unsupported type `java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>`

I already tried a `RealmList` of `RealmObjects` as well, without success.

```
@SerializedName("permitted_payment_types")
public RealmList<PaymentType> paymentTypes;

public class PaymentType extends RealmObject {
    public Integer type;
}
```

I tried a lot of links here, but none of them seemed to solve the problem.

Can anyone give me a light?

Answer (score 0):

Since your payment types aren't wrapped with any object just let the api response in your code returns List without wrapping it inside object for instance:

```
List<Integer> getPaymentTypes()
```

Assuming you're using retrofit

Answer (score 0):

It's actually just

```
RealmList<Integer> paymentTypes;
```

And it works since Realm 4.0.0.